# Angular 7 Material Design input element, problems with autocompletion

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material, material-design

In my Angular 7 I have a Material Design form with some input text fields; I don't implemented any autocomplete command o function inside, as you can see from the code below. I also tried to delete all navigation data from my Chrome browser.

```
(....)
<mat-form-field class="w-100">
        <input type="text" matInput formControlName="title">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="w-100">
        <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name">
</mat-form-field>
(....)
```

But, I see autocomplete suggestions which takes text not only from the current field but also from the other one. In other words, I see my old "title" values which in the past I inserted as suggested values also in other fields.

I am not sure it is related to Material Design itself; I searched other solutions but the "Material Autocompletion" which I found is not what I need because is a simple option combo box which takes value from a list (that is, as a drop down list). I also tried some HTML attributes but without success.

I attach an image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem like a problem with Angular Material, no. This just seems as the browser trying to autocomplete inputs in a form for you.
Try adding the following as the first attribute in your inputs:

```
 autocomplete="false"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but my purpose is to create a correct autocomplete (each field take the info I inserted in the correspondent field) and not completely disable).